# How to make AppleScript change the time in system preferences

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-yosemite

Okay the goal for this script is to make it where it changes the time back 1 second every 1 second. So in a way it is stop time on the mac. I got this far into the script. Note in () is what the script there is suppose to do. aka where you help me.

```
set pasword to ("my password")
tell application "System Preferences"
activate
end tell
delay 3
tell application "System Events"
tell process "System Preferences"
    click menu item "Date & Time" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
    delay 2
    tell window "Date & Time"
(click the authentication lock.)
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke pasword
            delay 1
tell application "System Events"
                keystroke return
                delay 1
(uncheck the set time data and time automatically checkbox)
delay 1
repeat
(select the seconds above the clock)
(click the top arrow right next to it)
(click save)
delay 1
end repeat
          end tell
        end tell
     end tell
   end tell
end tell
```

So that the whole script, I just got stuck in those areas and I'm looking for some help. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you keep `tell system events`ing. and did you try the record me option

Comment: @Kamin Pallaghy If your talking about the record button option that the top, then yes. It didn't even record me opening up system preferences, let alone all the other minor things. Did you try it yourself? Because for me it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an app called UIElementInspector to determine the names and hierarchies of the UI elements you are trying to interact with. For example, “the set time and date automatically checkbox” will have a name like “checkbox 3.”

However, my feeling is that you won’t be able to accomplish what you are trying to do with this script, because GUI scripting (when you tell System Events to interact with part of the GUI) has really poor timing. While it might be possible in a typical AppleScript to run a command and then wait a second and run another command and wait a second and run another command (although even there, you are going to get out of sync) with GUI Scripting, the first time you run this script it might take 2 seconds to go a second back, then 1.5 seconds, then 3 seconds, and then the second time you run the script it could be entirely different.

You would probably get a better result using the “do shell script” AppleScript command to set the time using command line shell scripting.

[Changing system date from the command line](https://bensmann.no/changing-system-date-from-terminal-os-x-recovery/)

Definitely be aware that you may see unexpected behavior from your entire computer if you are messing with the system clock in the manner that you describe, though. You could certainly see data loss (especially with network syncing) or you might crash your Mac or even make it unable to boot.

Comment: I've never heard the app UIElementInspector, and what does it exactly do? Wow, never realize that just playing around with time could destroy a Mac...  And is it even possible to make the Mac unable to bootable? Or is that worst case scenario? Because I wouldn't want to find out personally. In that case never mind this making this script if it is that destructive.

Comment: he can't even spend 2 seconds doing the task, as he needs to do it every seconds

Comment: Yes, it seems that this task is impossible due to timing issues is what I'm getting from you guy's... Maybe there is another approach to accomplishing this goal.